# What does the underscore motion do in vim?

Tags: vim

I do not understand the underscore motion in vim, at least not in the context of yank (y). My cheat sheet reads:

```
"soft" bol down
```

which I do not comprehend. If I use the motion alone, it seems to be the same as `^` which means: go to the first non-whitespace on the line.

However, if I use the motion with `y` then it yanks the whole line (like `yy` or `Y`). On the other hand, `y^` does not yank the whole line, but only up to the first non-whitespace character, exclusive — as you might expect.

So, what exactly is the underscore `_` motion supposed to do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Without a count, `^` and `_` are indeed equivalent, but the latter supports a count:

> ```
>   _  <underscore>         [count] - 1 lines downward, on the first non-blank
>                           character |linewise|.
> ```

The `linewise` explains your second observation: when used as a motion, it not just covers the text between the previous position and the new one, but the whole set of lines covered.

Carefully reading the `:help` provides these insights. You'll also see (by proximity), that the `_` command is closely related to `+` and `-`.

Comment: Hmmm, ok, then what is the difference between y2_ and y2+?

Comment: @TylerDurden The difference is 1 (line), as is the difference between `[count] - 1` and `[count]` for any value of `[count]`. As Ingo mentioned, it would do you some good to read vim's built-in help which is quite clear.

Comment: Why does the `_` command exist – why would someone prefer it to `+`?

Comment: Not to argue, but the help is a bit confusing on this one. `[count] - 1 lines downward` -- to me, it read "count: 1 lines downward" instead of the correct interpretation. I know, doesn't even make a lot of sense, but there's a little room for confusion there.